# Firebase in Ionic 2 app gets 1 minute delay on IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

In a standard Ionic 2 application, the firebase onAuthStatChanged takes exactly 1 minute to execute on Ios.  It works within milliseconds on browser but when deployed on to ios it always takes a minute.

```
const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        console.log("   onAuthStateChanged handler called after 1 minute..."); ...
```

I tried using angularfire2 and got the same result.

```
this.authState = auth$.getAuth();
    auth$.subscribe((state: FirebaseAuthState) => {
      console.log("authState received after 1 minute", state);
```

I tried rebuilding the ionic app, access origin setting is *, allow-navigation href is *.

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 
ios-sim version: 5.0.11 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.2
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.1 Build version 8E1000a

Comment: I have just discovered that this only happens with the npm module version 3.8.0.  Any previous version (e.g. 3.7.8) does not experience this 1 minute delay.

Comment: Got a message from Firebase, hope others don't waste hours like I had to: Thank you for reporting this issue.  You are correct, the onAuthStateChange function from 3.8.0 version has the mentioned delay. It happens when the plugins needed for OAuth sign in are not installed. The fix for this will be deployed on future releases. In the meantime these are the two possible workarounds:
Install the Oauth plugins mentioned https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova 
If you are not using Oauth sign in, you can downgrade to 3.7.8 version.